# React, How do I prevent the function from running again when the state changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

For example, when user A deletes a product, I transfer the product information to user B via SignalR. The information received by user B is transferred to the product model and that product is deleted from the state. In this way, instant data tracking is provided.

Every time products states changes, it repeats itself as much as the number of changes. The function crashes this browser, how can I solve it?

> First State Changes
>
> setProducts - normal work,
>
> Secon Time State Changes
>
> setProducts x2 work
>
> Third Time State Changes
>
> setProducts x6 work

How do i get it to run every once in a while?

```
  const [products, setProducts] = useState<API.ProductListDto[]>([]);
  const { initialState } = useModel('@@initialState');
  const { signalRService, , signalRConnectionId } = initialState || {};

  const getProductById = useCallback(
    (
      productId: string | undefined,
    ): API.ModelStateFunction<API.ProductDto | undefined> | undefined => {

      if (products && products.length > 0) {

        let product: API.ProductDto | undefined;
        let index: number | undefined;

        products.some((e) => {
          product = e.Products.find((c) => {
            return c.ProductId === productId;
          });

          if (product) return true;
          return false;
        });

        products.some((e) => {
          index = e.Products.findIndex((c) => {
            return c.ProductId === productId;
          });

          if (index !== -1) return true;
          return false;
        });

        return {
          entity: product,
          index,
        };
      }

      return undefined;
    },
    [products],
  );

  const getProductCategoryById = useCallback(
    (
      categoryId: string | undefined,
    ): API.ModelStateFunction<API.ProductListDto | undefined> | undefined => {
      if (products && products.length > 0) {

        return {
          entity: products.find((x) => x.ProductCategoryId === categoryId),
          index: products.findIndex((x) => x.ProductCategoryId === categoryId),
        };
      }

      return undefined;
    },
    [products],
  );

  const updateProductState = useCallback(
    (product: API.ProductDto) => {

      if (products && products.length > 0) {

        const cloneProdutcs: API.ProductListDto[] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(products));
        const stateProduct = getProductById(product.ProductId);
        if (stateProduct && stateProduct.entity) {

          const stateProductCategory = getProductCategoryById(
            stateProduct.entity.ProductCategoryId,
          );
          if (stateProductCategory && stateProductCategory.entity) {

            if (
              stateProduct.entity.ProductCategoryId === product.ProductCategoryId
            ) {

              cloneProdutcs[stateProductCategory.index!].Products[stateProduct.index!] =
                product;
            } else {
              const newProductCategory = getProductCategoryById(product.ProductCategoryId);

              if (newProductCategory && newProductCategory.entity) {
                cloneProdutcs[stateProductCategory.index!].Products = [
                  ...cloneProdutcs[stateProductCategory.index!].Products.filter(
                    (x) => x.ProductId !== product.ProductId,
                  ),
                ];
                cloneProdutcs[newProductCategory.index!].Products = [
                  ...cloneProdutcs[newProductCategory.index!].Products,
                  product,
                ];
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
          const category = getProductCategoryById(product.ProductCategoryId);

          if (category && category.entity) {

            cloneProdutcs[category.index!].Products = [
              ...cloneProdutcs[category.index!].Products,
              product,
            ];
          }
        }


        setProducts(cloneProdutcs);
      }
    },
    [getProductById, getProductCategoryById, products],
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    async function defineSignal() {
      if (signalRService) {
        if (signalRService.isConnected()) {
          if (!isEmpty(signalRConnectionId)) {
            await signalRService.define(
              'Product',
              (signalEntity: API.ProductDto, connectionId: string) => {
                if (signalRConnectionId !== connectionId) {
                  updateProductState(signalEntity);
                }
              },
            );

          }
        }
      }
    }

    defineSignal();
  }, [
    signalRService,
    signalRConnectionId,
    updateProductState,
  ]);
```

Comment: instead of using the products array itself on the dependency array, try to use `products.length`, and can you add console.log on the first line on useEffect callback to determine the bug here

Comment: Looks like when `products` changes, it triggers a change in `updateProductState`, `getProductCategoryById` and `getProductById`. But  then changes of the two former functions trigger back  an update of `updateProductState` since they are in its dependency array. What happens if you reduce the dependency array of `updateProductState` to  `[products]` only?

Comment: @exaucae When I do what you say, the console gives a warning. 'React Hook useCallback has missing dependencies: 'getProductById' and 'getProductCategoryById'. Either include them or remove the dependency array'.

Comment: Sure yes, what about the state update?

Comment: @exaucae same work, It repeats itself with every update.

Comment: @fadiomar It wants the products dependency, even if I write it this way, the result does not change.

Comment: I now think we have an issue we dependencies distribution in the array. `setProduct` is executed in a function that depends on `product`. Can we try this: `getProductCategoryById` depends on `categoryId`, `getProductById` depends on `productId`, and `updateProductState` depends on `getProductCategoryById` and `getProductById`?

Comment: @exaucae There must be a solution to this, whenever I want to update the state, it repeats itself as many times as the number of updates.

Comment: Have you tried suggestion in previous comment, @CodAvo?

Comment: @exaucae these dependencies you mentioned (categoryId, productId) are not a const variable that I cannot add to the dependency.

Comment: @exaucae I solved this issue, I use usePersistFn hooks instead of useCallback

Comment: there is a lot of HACK in this code for example change ```const cloneProdutcs: API.ProductListDto[] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(products));``` for ```const cloneProdutcs: API.ProductListDto[] = [...products];```, when u fix all your HACKS u find out what is wrong "usePersistFn" is not good solution

Comment: @Engazan why not a good solution? I tried all the variations, the functions repeat themselves every time the state changes, that's a problem.

Comment: @Engazan https://hooks.umijs.org/hooks/advanced/use-persist-fn